# System.Text.Json Deserialize nested object from API call - Data is wrapped in parent JSON property

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I have an API JSON response that wraps the data content in a `data` property, which looks like this:

```cs
{ 
   "data":{ 
      "email":"admin@example.com",
      "mobile":"+1555555123",
      "id":4,
      "first_name":"Merchant",
      "last_name":"Vendor",
      "role":"Merchant",
   }
}
```

So when making request for a User Object with a Library like `RequestSharp`, the `response.Content` has the content for the User wrapped in the `data` json property as it comes from the API. Code:

```cs
var request = RequestHelper.CreateTokenRequest(email, password); // Create the request from a helper
var client = new RestClient(BaseUrl); // create new RestSharp Client
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request); // execute the request
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

This is fine, but when I go to deserialize the json to an Object with `System.Text.Json`, like the following, will create the `User` object but will not assign any of the attributes, although this is sort of expected because the serializer is looking for properties with `first_name` and `last_name`... not `['data']['first_name']`

```cs
User account = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(response.Content, options);
```

How can I get the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` to ignore the `data` wrapper? In other API calls it may be the name of the Object such as `transaction` or `user`, either way, it wraps the data.

Other Notes:

I am targeting the latest .Net Core 3.1 and am migrating from Newtonsoft Json.Net

---

My User Object:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace MyApplication.Models
{
    public interface IUser
    {
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        string LastName { get; set; }
        string Email { get; set; }
        string Mobile { get; set; }
        string Id { get; set; }
        string Role { get; set; }
    }

    public class User : IUser
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("first_name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("last_name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("mobile")]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("role")]
        public string Role { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Update after resolution:

I selected the answer from u/Nikunj Kakadiya below as something that would work and was most similar to what I ended up doing.

I created a generic template based container class to handle the `data` like this:

```cs
public class Container<T>
{
    [JsonPropertyName("data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

I then used that container class to wrap the returned json contents from the API call, like this:

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    AllowTrailingCommas = true
};

Container<User> accountContainer = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Container<User>>(response.Content, options);
User account = accountContainer.Data;
```

Additionally, as u/Pavel Anikhouski noted, my serialization of the `User` class led to an error that required me to create a custom converter for the `id` field. The API returns the `id` as an integer although it is a string in the `User` class. This was the error I ran into which was initially confusing but I was able to figure out pretty quickly: `ERROR: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.data.id | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 77.`

Here is the custom converter `IntToStringConverter`:

```cs
public class IntToStringConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) => reader.GetInt32().ToString();

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        string value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
}
```

and then changed the `User` Class to use the customer converter:

```cs
...
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IntToStringConverter))]
    public string Id { get; set; }
...
```

Comment: There is an error _Cannot get the value of a token type 'Number' as a string._ for `id` property

Comment: Do you still need an answer?  There are several working answers below.  If you really don't care about the root property name you could always deserialize to a dictionary and take the first value, i.e. `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, User>>(response.Content, options).Values.SingleOrDefault();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make one another class. That is given below

```
Public class UserData
{
    public User data { get; set; }; 
}
```

Now you can Deserialize data using new class called UserData like below

```
UserData account = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserData>(response.Content, options);
```

Comment: But OP mentioned that _In other API calls it may be the name of the Object such as `transaction` or `user`_

Comment: This works although I ended up creating a template container class. Check out the solution above

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to get a `User` object using `System.Text.Json` API without specifying a name of property `data` from your JSON sample

```
{ 
   "data":{ 
      "email":"admin@example.com",
      "mobile":"+1555555123",
      "id":4,
      "first_name":"Merchant",
      "last_name":"Vendor",
      "role":"Merchant",
   }
}
```

by the following code

```cs
var document = JsonDocument.Parse(json, new JsonDocumentOptions { AllowTrailingCommas = true });
var enumerator = document.RootElement.EnumerateObject();
if (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var userJson = enumerator.Current.Value.GetRawText();
    var user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(userJson,
        new JsonSerializerOptions {AllowTrailingCommas = true});
}
```

In the sample above the [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.1) is loaded, than `RootElement` is enumerated to get the first nested object as text to deserialize into `User` instance.

It's more easier to get a property by name like `document.RootElement.GetProperty("data");`, but the name can be different actually, according to your question. Accessing through [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.item?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonElement_Item_System_Int32_), like `document.RootElement[0]` is also not possible, because it works only when `ValueKind` of an element is `Array`, not the `Object`, like in your case

I've also changed the `"id":4,` to `"id":"4",`, because getting an error

> Cannot get the value of a token type 'Number' as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object like this:

```
  public class Data
   {
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    }

   public class RootObject
   {
    public Data data { get; set; }
   }
```

then

```
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(JsonData);
```

then you can access the data like the following:

```
RootObject.Data.email ;
RootObject.Data.first_name
```

Also, anytime you need to convert JSON string to C# POCO class you can use a tool like this : http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score -2):

Either you get rid of the data object or you can write a custom json Converter. I suggest to change the sent data or just consume it as it is because what you are trying to do is not a best practice.