# System.Text.Json - Deserialize nested object as string

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, deserialization, system.text.json

I'm trying to use the `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` to deserialize the model partially, so one of the properties is read as string that contains the original JSON.

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

The example code

```
var json = @"{
                 ""Id"": 1,
                 ""Name"": ""Some Name"",
                 ""Info"": {
                     ""Additional"": ""Fields"",
                     ""Are"": ""Inside""
                 }
             }";

var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SomeModel>(json);
```

should produce the model, which `Info` property contains the Info object from the original JSON as string:

```
{
    "Additional": "Fields",
    "Are": "Inside"
}
```

It doesn't work out of the box and throws an exception:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.

What have I tried so far:

```
public class InfoToStringConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return reader.GetString();
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and apply it in the model as

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(InfoToStringConverter))]
public string Info { get; set; }
```

and add in the options to `JsonSerializer`

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new InfoToStringConverter());
var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SomeModel>(json, options);
```

Still, it throws the same exception:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.

What is the right recipe to cook what I need? It worked in a similar way using `Newtonsoft.Json`.

**Update**

For me it is important to keep the nested JSON object as original as possible. So, I'd avoid options like to deserialize as `Dictionary` and serialize back, because I'm afraid to introduce undesirable changes.

Comment: You can also create a class and store the `Info` value in its instance, like it's done in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568647/system-text-json-deserialize-nested-object-from-api-call-data-is-wrapped-in-pa)

Comment: To achieve the expected behavior with custom converter you can have a look at [`JsonValueConverterKeyValuePair`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/81bf79fd9aa75305e55abe2f7e9ef3f60624a3a1/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/JsonValueConverterKeyValuePair.cs) and see how to properly read and write `StartObject` and `EndObject` of complicated json structure

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Found a right way how to correctly read the nested JSON object inside the `JsonConverter`. The complete solution is the following:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(InfoToStringConverter))]
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

public class InfoToStringConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        using (var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
        {
            return jsonDoc.RootElement.GetRawText();
        }
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the code itself there is no need even to create options:

```
var json = @"{
                 ""Id"": 1,
                 ""Name"": ""Some Name"",
                 ""Info"": {
                     ""Additional"": ""Fields"",
                     ""Are"": ""Inside""
                 }
             }";

var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SomeModel>(json);
```

The raw JSON text in the `Info` property contains even extra spaces introduced in the example for nice readability.

And there is no mixing of model representation and its serialization as remarked @PavelAnikhouski in his answer.

Comment: Good job, you've figured out how to do it with custom converter:) Just a quick note, without `Write` implementation you can't serialize it back

Comment: This is great thank you.  You might make a small performance improvement if the value is null :             
 if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Null)
 {
  return null;
 }

Comment: for me it doesn't work if the type of `Info` is a `record` that contains a single `string` field, because jsonDoc.RootElement.GetRawText() returns the double quotes around the string value as part of the string! If I just try to brute-force it (remove the quotes myself) I trap myself into a corner as later on another deserialization inexplicably provides `Info` (jsonDoc.rootElement) already as an Object instead of a String, so the brute force method fails.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a [`JsonExtensionData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute?view=netcore-3.1) attribute for that and declare a `Dictionary<string, JsonElement>` or `Dictionary<string, object>` property in your model to store this information

```cs
public class SomeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JsonElement> ExtensionData { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Data
    {
        get
        {
            return ExtensionData?["Info"].GetRawText();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add an additional property to get a string from this dictionary by `Info` key. In code above the `Data` property will contain the expected string

```
{
    "Additional": "Fields",
    "Are": "Inside"
}
```

For some reasons adding the property with the same name `Info` doesn't work, even with `JsonIgnore`. Have a look at [Handle overflow JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#handle-overflow-json) for details.

You can also declare the `Info` property as `JsonElement` type and get raw text from it

```cs
public class SomeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public JsonElement Info { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SomeModel>(json);
var rawString = model.Info.GetRawText();
```

But it will cause a mixing of model representation and its serialization.

Another option is to parse the data using `JsonDocument`, enumerate properties and parse them one by one, like that

```cs
var document = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
foreach (var token in document.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
{
    if (token.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Number)
    {
        if(token.Value.TryGetInt32(out int number))
        {
        }
    }
    if (token.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.String)
    {
        var stringValue = token.Value.GetString();
    }
    if (token.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object)
    {
        var rawContent = token.Value.GetRawText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

a quick addendum to the accepted answer:

If you need to write raw JSON values as well, here is an implementation of the `Write` method for the converter:

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(value))
    {
        document.RootElement.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

As outlined in the dotnet runtime repo on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1784), this seems to be the "proper" way to workaround the fact that they decided not to implement a `WriteRawValue` method.

Answer (score 0):

I create a text converter as solution to the problem. I use part of the solution given by kyrylc, and create a custom text converter that manage all that I need with string, in this case I don't need to use a header:

Converter:

```
public class StringDoubleConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<string>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allow to convert a Double number to string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader"></param>
    /// <param name="typeToConvert"></param>
    /// <param name="options"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
        {
            var stringValue = reader.GetDouble();
            return stringValue.ToString();
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            return reader.GetString();
        }

        using var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
        return jsonDoc.RootElement.GetRawText();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write the value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="options"></param>
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
    }

}
```

I added the converter to JsonSerializerOptions (please ignore the setting that you don't need)

```
      this.serializerOptionReceive = new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
            
            NumberHandling = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString,
            DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
            WriteIndented = true
        };
       serializerOptionReceive.Converters.Add(new StringDoubleConverter());
```

and use the created serialization option, when I deserialize the object..

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<yourobject>(contentResponse, serializerOptionReceive);
```